# A Pythagorean problem

Tags: triangles

We have two points F1, F2. F1-F2 is 21m.
We have a point (P) outside the line.

The line from F1-P is called D1.
The line from F2-P is called D2.

P is 12m away from F1-F2 on a straight line crossing F1-F2 in (N) dividing the triangle F1-P-F2 into two 90*triangles.

[image: Problem]

Task A) Use the Pythagorean theorem to show that $\sqrt{D1^2-12^2} + \sqrt{D2^2-12^2}=21$

Since $K1^2 + K2^2 = H^2$ then $D1^2-12^2=21-N>F2$ and $D2^2-12^2=21-N>F1$ 
And then **$\sqrt{D1^2-12^2} + \sqrt{D2^2-12^2}=21$**

Task B)

$D1=D2+7m$

**Find D1 and D2.**

Halp!! I have tried and tried, isolating square roots and quadrating both sides then repeating the process and using the quadratic equation but i get the wrong answer each time. The answer is supposed to be D1=20m D2=13m but i can't get that answer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is task B:

Let $x = N-F2$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
x^2+12^2&=D_2^2 \\
(21-x)^2+12^2&=D_1^2 \\
D_1&=D_2+7
\end{align}
$$
Substitute the last equation in the second to get
$$
\begin{align}
x^2+12^2&=D_2^2 \\
441-42 x + x^2 +12^2&=D_2^2+14~D_2 + 49
\end{align}
$$
Solve for $D_2$ from the first equation and substitute in the second to get
$$
14\,\sqrt{{x}^{2}+144}=42\,x-392
$$
Square both sides and re-arrange
$$
1568\,{x}^{2}-32928\,x+125440=0
$$
Solve to get 
$$ x = 5, 16$$
Now go  back and find $D_2$ and $D_1$. $x=16$ gives *negative* values for $D_1$ and $D_2$.
So the answer is
$$
x=5, D1=20, D2=13
$$

*Note*: For task A, solve for $x$ from the first equation and substitute in the second or just observe that the two square roots are F2 to N and from N to F1, so they add to 21